# Error in exporting data.frame in excel/csv using R

Tags: r

My JSON file looks like below:

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : "93ccbdb6-8947",
  "uiSearchRequest" : {
    "travelDate" : 20151206,
    "travelDuration" : 7,
    "shopperDuration" : 30,
    "oneWay" : false,
    "userId" : "ATP1KKP",
    "queryId" : "93ccbdb6-8947",
    "subRequests" : [{
        "origin" : "WAS",
        "destination" : "LON",
        "carrier" : "AA",
        "fareClasses" : "",
        "owrt" : "1,2"
      }]
  },
  "downloadCount" : 0,
  "requestDate" : 20151205,
  "totalRecords" : 0,
  "status" : "SUCCESS"
}

/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : "b736c374-b8ae",
  "uiSearchRequest" : {
    "travelDate" : 20151206,
    "travelDuration" : 7,
    "shopperDuration" : 30,
    "oneWay" : false,
    "userId" : "ATP1KKP",
    "queryId" : "b736c374-b8ae",
    "subRequests" : [{
        "origin" : "WAS",
        "destination" : "LON",
        "carrier" : "AA",
        "fareClasses" : "",
        "owrt" : "1,2"
      }]
  },
  "downloadCount" : 0,
  "requestDate" : 20151205,
  "totalRecords" : 0,
  "status" : "SUCCESS"
}

/* 2 */
{
  "_id" : "3312605f-8304",
  "uiSearchRequest" : {
    "travelDate" : 20151206,
    "travelDuration" : 7,
    "shopperDuration" : 30,
    "oneWay" : false,
    "userId" : "ATP1SXE",
    "queryId" : "3312605f-8304",
    "subRequests" : [{
        "origin" : "LON",
        "destination" : "IAD",
        "carrier" : "AA",
        "fareClasses" : "",
        "owrt" : "1,2"
      }]
  },
  "downloadCount" : 2,
  "requestDate" : 20151205,
  "totalRecords" : 0,
  "status" : "SUCCESS"
}

/* 3 */
{
  "_id" : "6b668cfa-9b79",
  "uiSearchRequest" : {
    "travelDate" : 20151206,
    "travelDuration" : 7,
    "shopperDuration" : 30,
    "oneWay" : false,
    "userId" : "ATP1NXA",
    "queryId" : "6b668cfa-9b79",
    "subRequests" : [{
        "origin" : "WAS",
        "destination" : "LON",
        "carrier" : "AA",
        "fareClasses" : "",
        "owrt" : "1,2"
      }]
  },
  "downloadCount" : 1,
  "requestDate" : 20151205,
  "totalRecords" : 1388,
  "status" : "SUCCESS"
}

/* 4 */
{
  "_id" : "41c373a1-e4cb",
  "uiSearchRequest" : {
    "travelDate" : 20151206,
    "travelDuration" : 7,
    "shopperDuration" : 30,
    "oneWay" : false,
    "userId" : "ATP6CXS",
    "queryId" : "41c373a1-e4cb",
    "subRequests" : [{
        "origin" : "WAS",
        "destination" : "LON",
        "carrier" : "AA",
        "fareClasses" : "",
        "owrt" : "1,2"
      }]
  },
  "downloadCount" : 0,
  "requestDate" : 20151205,
  "totalRecords" : 1388,
  "status" : "SUCCESS"
}

/* 5 */
{
  "_id" : "2c8331c4-21ca",
  "uiSearchRequest" : {
    "travelDate" : 20151206,
    "travelDuration" : 7,
    "shopperDuration" : 30,
    "oneWay" : false,
    "userId" : "ATP1KKP",
    "queryId" : "2c8331c4-21ca",
    "subRequests" : [{
        "origin" : "WAS",
        "destination" : "LON",
        "carrier" : "AA",
        "fareClasses" : "",
        "owrt" : "1,2"
      }]
  },
  "downloadCount" : 0,
  "requestDate" : 20151205,
  "totalRecords" : 1388,
  "status" : "SUCCESS"
}

/* 6 */
{
  "_id" : "71a09900-1c13",
  "uiSearchRequest" : {
    "travelDate" : 20151206,
    "travelDuration" : 7,
    "shopperDuration" : 30,
    "oneWay" : false,
    "userId" : "ATP6CXS",
    "queryId" : "71a09900-1c13",
    "subRequests" : [{
        "origin" : "WAS",
        "destination" : "LON",
        "carrier" : "AF",
        "fareClasses" : "",
        "owrt" : "1,2"
      }, {
        "origin" : "WAS",
        "destination" : "LON",
        "carrier" : "AA",
        "fareClasses" : "",
        "owrt" : "1,2"
      }, {
        "origin" : "WAS",
        "destination" : "LON",
        "carrier" : "DL",
        "fareClasses" : "",
        "owrt" : "1,2"
      }, {
        "origin" : "WAS",
        "destination" : "LON",
        "carrier" : "LH",
        "fareClasses" : "",
        "owrt" : "1,2"
      }, {
        "origin" : "WAS",
        "destination" : "LON",
        "carrier" : "BA",
        "fareClasses" : "",
        "owrt" : "1,2"
      }]
  },
  "downloadCount" : 0,
  "requestDate" : 20151205,
  "totalRecords" : 6941,
  "status" : "SUCCESS"
}

/* 7 */
{
  "_id" : "a036a42a-918b",
  "uiSearchRequest" : {
    "travelDate" : 20151206,
    "travelDuration" : 7,
    "shopperDuration" : 30,
    "oneWay" : false,
    "userId" : "ATP1MMM",
    "queryId" : "a036a42a-918b",
    "subRequests" : [{
        "origin" : "WAS",
        "destination" : "LON",
        "carrier" : "AA",
        "fareClasses" : "",
        "owrt" : "1,2"
      }]
  },
  "downloadCount" : 0,
  "requestDate" : 20151205,
  "totalRecords" : 1388,
  "status" : "SUCCESS"
}

/* 8 */
{
  "_id" : "c547be36-805c",
  "uiSearchRequest" : {
    "travelDate" : 20151206,
    "travelDuration" : 7,
    "shopperDuration" : 30,
    "oneWay" : false,
    "userId" : "ATP1SXB",
    "queryId" : "c547be36-805c",
    "subRequests" : [{
        "origin" : "CHI",
        "destination" : "LON",
        "carrier" : "BA",
        "fareClasses" : "",
        "owrt" : "1,2"
      }]
  },
  "downloadCount" : 2,
  "requestDate" : 20151205,
  "totalRecords" : 1072,
  "status" : "SUCCESS"
}
```

My code is below:

```
raw <- readLines("mydata.txt")
#since my JSON file isn't in the correct format, I've added the below 3 lines of code

# get rid of the "/* 0 */" lines
json <- grep("^/\\* [0-9]* \\*/", raw, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)

# add missing comma after }
n <- length(json)
json[-n] <- gsub("^}$", "},", json[-n])

# add brakets at the beginning and end
json <- c("[", json, "]")


library(jsonlite)
table <- fromJSON(json)

final <- flatten(table)
final1 <- as.data.frame.matrix(final)

class(final1)
[1] "data.frame"

write.xlsx(final1, file="JSON2excel.xlsx",row.names = FALSE)
file.show("JSON2excel.xlsx")
```

I'm getting the below error:

```
Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellValue", value) : 
  method setCellValue with signature ([Ljava/lang/String;)V not found
In addition: Warning message:
In if (is.na(value)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I've browsed through multiple stackoverflow questions having this same type of error but the solutions just isn't working in my case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like an `rJava` problem

Comment: @Carl I have the rJava function running too, if that's what you're hinting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for error is your end result dataframe contains nested dataframes for the nested subrequest portion in the json file. You can see with `str(final1)`. So even base functions `write.table()` and `write.csv()` including the xlsx package's `write.xlsx()` will fail in outputting to flat formats.

Consider flattening by binding the subrequests data frame and merging them to larger final1 columns using the row's id variable. Ultimately, you will obtain a dataframe of 13 observations (not the 9 elements from json, because one of them contained 5 nested subrequests: id = 71a09900-1c13).

```
# SUBREQUEST BINDING (PULLING CORRESPONDING ID)
dfList <- lapply(1:nrow(final1), function(i){
                cbind(id = final1$`_id`[[i]],
                      final1$uiSearchRequest.subRequests[[i]])
})

# USE DPLYR'S bind_rows() IF dfs DIFFER IN NUMBER OF COLUMNS
subdf <- bind_rows(dfList) 
# subdf <-  data.frame(do.call(rbind, dfList))

# FINAL1 EXTRACTION
fdf <-  data.frame(
                id = final1$`_id`,
                travelDate = final1$uiSearchRequest.travelDate,
                travelDuration = final1$uiSearchRequest.travelDuration,
                shopperDuration = final1$uiSearchRequest.shopperDuration,
                oneway = final1$uiSearchRequest.oneWay,
                userId = final1$uiSearchRequest.userId,
                queryId = final1$uiSearchRequest.queryId,
                downloadCount = final1$downloadCount,
                requestDate = final1$requestDate,
                totalRecords = final1$totalRecords,
                status = final1$status,

                stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                row.names = NULL
              )

# MERGE
finaldf <- merge(fdf, subdf, by="id")
```

Alternatively, you can bind iteratively by rows:

```
dfList <- lapply(1:nrow(final1), function(i){      
              data.frame(
                id = final1$`_id`[[i]],
                travelDate = final1$uiSearchRequest.travelDate[[i]],
                travelDuration = final1$uiSearchRequest.travelDuration[[i]],
                shopperDuration = final1$uiSearchRequest.shopperDuration[[i]],
                oneway = final1$uiSearchRequest.oneWay[[i]],
                userId = final1$uiSearchRequest.userId[[i]],
                queryId = final1$uiSearchRequest.queryId[[i]],
                final1$uiSearchRequest.subRequests[[i]],
                downloadCount = final1$downloadCount[[i]],
                requestDate = final1$requestDate[[i]],
                totalRecords = final1$totalRecords[[i]],
                status = final1$status[[i]],

                stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                row.names = NULL
              )      
         })

finaldf <- do.call(rbind_rows, dfList)
```

Comment: When I ran the line dfList <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i){ cbind(id = final1$_id[[i]], final1$uiSearchRequest.subRequests[[i]]) }) I got the following error even though there are no null values in final1: Error in 1:nrow(df) : argument of length 0

Comment: Whoops...`nrow()` should use final1 not df. Also, the column *_id* must be wrapped in backticks. By itself, underscores like spaces are not accepted as identifiers.

Comment: Please explain your edit. What package is `rbind_rows`? Dplyr uses `bind_rows` and plyr uses `rbind.fill`? Also, where is the extra column coming from? Is your posted snippet not actual live data?

Comment: Yes Dplyr uses bind_rows, so I've called that function in my code. The posted snippet is just a sample of the live data since the live data contained more than 6k entries. I realized the column problem later while encountering the 'numbers of columns of arguments do not match' error